# Mongoose.js - "Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel" when I'm only saving once

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, promise

I have a database model that looks like this:

```
ParentModel: {
  children: [id1, id2, ...],
  active: Boolean
}

ChildModel: {
  id: ...,
  otherInfo: {...}
}
```

ParentModel has an array of IDs that refer to ChildModel documents. I want to update each of the Child documents, then update the Parent document. My code looks like this:

```js
async function activate(parent_doc) { // this is called from an express endpoint
    parent_doc.active = true;
    await Promise.all(parent_doc.children.map(function(child_id) {
        return ChildModel.findById(child_id).then(function(child_doc) {
            // Update child info
            child_doc.save();
        });
    }));
    console.log("saving doc");
    parent_doc.save();
}
```

I'm certain that the children are unique and child_doc is a different value each time, but that's not relevant anyway because that's not the call that throws. On the `parent_doc.save()` call, I'm getting a ParallelSaveError (Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel). This is only called once, however. "saving doc" is only printed once and there's only one call to `activate()` in the codebase. I have no idea where this error could be coming from.

EDIT: I've updated the code due to incorrect promise handling of the children, but the result is the same.

Comment: Does the `parent_doc.active` flag need to be lowered?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 That's the whole reason I'm saving the document. I want to set it to true and persist it.

Comment: Doh! In that case, please ignore me. :-)